# 2 networks on unmanageable switch

Tags: networking, wifi

I have 2 ISP's in my office and both are connected in one switch. One is TATA and one is ACT. TATA will release IP's from their server (100.118.11.1 series). I have connected AP's in my switch, so that DHCP users will get IP's from TATA.

I have a firewall (Quickheal) which we are using for our staff and IP series is 192.168.15.1 series, manually I am configuring IP's in their laptops.

Here is the problem I am getting continuous packet losses in my staff laptop.

Please help me someone.

Comment: Does the packet loss happen on wired, wireless or both?

Answer (score 1):

No offense mate but your situation seems like a mess.
I would advise you to:

1. get a basic router which supports two ISP. For example: cisco RV042G  Gigabit Dual WAN VPN Router.
2. Connect your primary ISP to the WAN port (seems to be TATA) and secondary ISP to DMZ port
3. Configure the router as load balancer or as connection fallback (I prefer that)
4. Configure the firewall, NAT and DHCP for the internal network
5. Enjoy